# How can I make a T Fip Flop with commands in 1.13+?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm new to command blocks and I was watching [this garage door tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhcFZorJhes) which uses the following command to implement a T Flip Flop, i.e. it alternates between success and failure upon each activation:

```
testforblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:command_block -1 {SuccessCount:0}
```

However, I'm using Minecraft 1.16.5 - I'm aware that `testforblock` was removed in Minecraft 1.13 and onwards in favour of `execute if`.

I tried the following:

```
execute if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:command_block{SuccessCount:0}
```

However this seems to result in continuous success, <s>due to the missing `dataValue` (set to `-1`) in the original command</s>. edit: `-1` is the same as not specifying anything [according to the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/testforblock?oldid=1248299)

The following doesn't work due to a syntax error:

```
execute if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:command_block -1 {SuccessCount:0}
```

How can I implement a T Flip Flop using a command block in Minecraft Java Edition versions 1.13 and newer?

Comment: I've removed the minecraft-redstone tag. Implementing T flip-flop in redstone is pretty easy but completely different than doing it with command blocks.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I've updated the final line to indicate my question more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the technique used to test for a success count in previous versions does not work in 1.13+, due to unknown reasons.

To invert a score you can check if the score is not 1, and store the success of that check back to the same score:

```
execute store success score @s objective unless score @s objective matches 1
```